# Anybody know how to delete a file from QML without resorting to a C++ plugin?

Tags: application-development, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

Anybody know how to delete a file from QML without resorting to a C++ plugin?

It should be possible to do in the folder that my app uses for data storage.